# How to get style attribute(margin-left) a positive value with XPATH

Tags: xpath

I have the following html

```
<ul id="ref_1876" data-typeid="n">
   <li style="margin-left: -18px">/li>
   <li style="margin-left: -10px"></li>
   <li style="margin-left: 16px"></li>
   <li style="margin-left: 17px"></li>
   <li style="margin-left: 18px"></li>
   <li style="margin-left: 14px"></li>
   <li style="margin-left: 14px"></li>
   <li style="margin-left: 14px"></li>
   <li style="margin-left: 14px"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get all "li" of the value of the margin-left is positive with XPATH.

At this stage I have the following code which takes all "li"

```
('//ul[contains(@data-typeid, "n")]/li')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Xpath 2.0, you could use the **[matches](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches)** function with a regular expression, something like:

```
... li[matches(@style, "margin\-left\: [0-9]+px")]
```

With Xpath 1.0 there is no `matches`, but maybe you could use:

```
... li[contains(@style, "margin-left:") and not(contains(@style, "margin-left: -"))]
```

Comment: nice one! :) why do you need the `and not(` and not just `not(` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl I added the first condition just in case there are any `<li>` without "margin-left". And the `and` operator (or another one) is required between two expressions. Xpath's `not` is a function, not an operator (anyway, it would be an unary operator, and I'd still need another one between the expressions)

Comment: @AJPerez Hmmm, just `//li[not(contains(@style, "margin-left: -"))]` didn't worked for me. This is what I wanted to answer in the first place

Comment: Maybe you had a typo? Your expression does work, I've just tried it here: http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php and works as expected (once I fixed the first `<li>` in the question's code, which is missing a `<`).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone has a better answer. The following XPath does the job, but it expects that there will always be a `margin-left:` and `px` in the attribute `style`:

```
//ul[contains(@data-typeid, "n")]/li[number(substring-before(substring-after(@style, 'margin-left:'), 'px')) > 0]
```